# Is O(k*n) in this case linear?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, arrays, linear-complexity

Problem: find sum of k element in array and it is biggest?
time complexity of my algorithm is O(k*n).Is it linear complexity?

Comment: "and it is biggest": what does that mean ?

Comment: It may be helpful in this case to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) illustrating the code or pseudocode you were trying.

Comment: @Yves Daoust it means find kth largest elements.

Comment: Do you mean the k largest elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the algorithm is linear in $k$ and linear in $n$, whatever $k$ and $n$ mean. But it is quadratic in $(k,n)$.

Comment: I am expecting an explanation from the downvoter.

Comment: I'm curious too.. someone downvoted all of the answers, though, so maybe they don't like us answering the question. Still a bit irritating, it's my first answer here.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica: don't worry, this is common on StackExchange.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Just so you know, I did not downvote your post 

Answer (score 0):

By definition, time complexity of a problem is defined due to its input size (please check this [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity#Complexity_as_a_function_of_input_size) on Wikipedia).
As input, you get an array of length $n$ ($O(n)$) and **ONE** number $k$ ($O(1)$), so that the input size of your problem is $O(n)$ in overall. On the other hand, the time complexity of your algorithm is $O(kn)$ so that you can't call that algorithm linear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to challenge the premise of the question: your algorithm should be `O(n)`, so either your implementation is wrong or your analysis of the complexity is wrong. This is a solution to this that is definitely `O(n)` (or, to be more precise, $\theta(n)$ because the loop will always take exactly `n` steps):

```
public void LargestAndSum(int[] numbers, int k)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int largest = int.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i < k)
        {
            sum += numbers[i];
        }
        
        if (numbers[i] > largest)
        {
            largest = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {sum}. Largest: {largest}");
}
```

It's tempting to look at the `i < k` part and say "see? It's `O(kn)`!" However, this isn't true, and the reason is the following: it does the `i < k` comparison exactly `n` times. The operation in the loop happens `k` times (where $k \le n$), so that term is dominated by `n`. So there are two comparisons that will happen exactly `n` times, an addition operation that will happen $k \le n$ times, and an assignment operation that will happen at least once (in the case where the first number is the largest in the array) and at most `n` times (in the case that `numbers` is sorted in ascending order). Therefore `O(n)`.

Side note: obviously in actual production code you would want to validate that $numbers \neq null$ and $k \le n$ because it wouldn't make sense for $k > n$. I did not include the argument validation in the code, though.

You may also want to read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301287/what-is-the-difference-between-onk-and-onk-in-time-complexity) on the difference between `O(kn)` and `O(n + k)`.

Comment: I think you misunderstanding my question. My problem is find kth largest elements in array.

Comment: Ex: input n=7, aray: 9 4 2 5 3 8 1 and k=3. then output is 9 5 8